# Jackson Fail to Deserialize Request Body due to no Creators, like default constructor, exist in Kotlin Spring

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I received error upon Jackson request deserialization as the destination class written below

```
data class FooRequest(val param1: String)
```

Actually this issue easily solved by add `@JsonProperty` annotation, also the reason that Jackson needs a **no-args** constructor is understandable. But I'm a bit curious, how can such error doesn't occurring when the destination class contains more than one property, like

```
data class BarRequest(val param1: String, val param2: String)
```

The full code written below

```
data class FooRequest(val param1: String)

data class BarRequest(val param1: String, val param2: String)

@RestController
class FooController {

    @PostMapping("/foo")
    fun foo(@RequestBody @Valid request: FooRequest) {}

    @PostMapping("/bar")
    fun bar(@RequestBody @Valid request: BarRequest) {}

}
```

Here are the CURL for both success and fail requests. `foo` endpoint is fail but the `bar` endpoint is success

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8003/foo' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "param1": "value1"
}'

curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8003/bar' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2"
}'
```

Also here's the error message

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `controller.FooRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `controller.FooRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]

Also in case anyone asking why am I using `javax.validation @Valid` annotation is because I need to make sure that the request doesn't contains blank string, since such case would pass kotlin non-null checking

Comment: Do you have a sample of the json that should be deserialized that throws the exception? Otherwise, it is hard to see where it is going wrong. Also, do note that jackson has a kotlin module. Adding that might change the behaviour when you are working with jackson and kotlin.

Comment: It should work. Do you mind adding the Controller code? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias code added already, thank you

Comment: It looks fine. Can you please add your dependencies to the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### First option: no-arg plugin

Kotlin no-arg plugin might help you.
This plugin can add a no-arg constructor to classes although they are data classes.

#### Second option: default parameter value

Or, maybe you can specify default values for each param.

```kotlin
data class BarRequest(val param1: String = "", val param2: String = "")
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the solution, I'm just curious how can when you have only one property the jackson throws error, but not when multiple property found

Comment: Ok, I've misunderstood your question. I set up a demo proejct based on your code, but I can't reproduce your error.
When I set up foo endpoint and I call this endpoint with your cURL command, it works fine.
I think the only different parts are the gradle build script. The reason causing the problem will be there.
Please describe your situation more detail to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem as well. It has something to do with the fact that Jackson deals with single-argument creators differently than multiple argument creators.

Here is one issue in which this is discussed, with only workarounds as of now: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/170.

I recommend switching from Jackson to kotlinx-serialization, which is supported [out of the box](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/languages/kotlin/web.html#kotlin-multiplatform-serialization) by recent versions of Spring.